# Dataframe replace does not work on json in Python

Tags: python, json, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe final_data which contains columns as ['rulelogid','final_value']

Though they are orginally of string type I still cast them into `str` using

```
final_data['rulelogid']=final_data['rulelogid'].astype('str')
final_data['final_value']=final_data['final_value'].astype('str')
```

The data inside the column final_value for a row looks like this:

```
"{"
"invoice_description"
":"
"{"
"RuleType7"
":"
"{"
"nruleid"
":"
"-1"
","
"taxonomyid"
":"
"-1"
"}"
"}"
"}"
```

I have extra double quotes from converting an already existing JSON in a dataframe to json again in the final_data. I tried to cast the column as string and replace the `""` with a single `"`. But the replace doesn't seem to  work.

```
final_data=final_data.replace(to_replace=['""'],value=['"'],regex=True)
```

The result should look like this:

```
{
"invoice_description": {
    "RuleType7": {
        "nruleid": "-1",
        "taxonomyid": "-1"
                 }
    }
}
```

But even after execution my data looks like before only.
Can someone point me out where I am making a mistake? Thanks for reading :)

**EDIT 1:**
I have 7 dataframes that have data like this for each ruletype:

```
*rulelogid*       *RuleType3*
872564          {"RuleType7": {"nruleid": "-1","taxonomyid": "-1"}
...              ....
```

I merge all these dataframes into a `final_data` that now has 8 columns (i.e.) `rulelogid` and all the ruletypes. Now I want to convert this dataframe to JSON excluding the `rulelogid` column. So I use the following code:

```
df_rulelogid = pd.DataFrame(final_data['rulelogid'])
final_data=final_data.drop(['rulelogid'],axis=1)
data_q=[]
for i in final_data.index:
    data=final_data.loc[i].to_json()
    data_q.append(data)
df=pd.DataFrame(data_q)
df.columns=['final_value']
final_data=pd.concat([df_rulelogid,df],axis=1)
```

And I get the sample data that I posted. Which is not how I want the JSON to look.

**EDIT 2:**

After implementing a suggestion to use `apply(ast.literal_eval)`, all the data is converted into proper json format but with single quotes.Is there some way I can change all the single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: Your sample is in 17 rows or in 1 row?

Comment: The data got linted that way. All of the sample data exists only in one row. It is one JSON

Comment: Ok, how do you read json? By [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) function? Do you need parse data from json to dataframe as scalar values?

Comment: There is another dataframe (7 of them) that have data stored as `"RuleType7": {  "nruleid": "-1",  "taxonomyid": "-1" }` 

For each rule type. I am merging the data from the 7 dataframes into a single dataframe. so now at the end I have 8 columns including `rulelogid`. I am ultimately merging the columns to form a JSON like the one I pasted.

Comment: First I test replace and for me it works perfectly. So seems problem is something else. So maybe the best is add json sample, how do you create dataframe for simulate your problem. Thank you.

Comment: json files are a bitch!

Comment: The EDIT 2 solved my proble @LiamLarsen . But I dont want single quotes. Problem after problem :(